# Getting Access violation reading location but not sure why

Tags: c++

I am working on a c++ class assignment. I am getting the Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCDCD. I can't figure out what.

Here is the roster constructor where the array of pointers is defined. It has to be and array of pointers per the instructions.

```
roster::roster(int capacity)
{
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->lastIndex = -1;
    this->students = new student*[capacity];
}
```

Here is my add method. In debug all the values are correct. Even when I new up the students it seems like it is there but it has a different pointer address after it gets past that point.

```
void roster::add(string studentId, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, Degree degreeType)
    {
        int openArrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            if (students[i] == NULL) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                openArrayIndex++;
            }
        }

        int daysInCourses[3]{ daysInCourse1, daysInCourse2, daysInCourse3 };

        switch (degreeType)
        {
        case SECURITY: {
            students[openArrayIndex] = new securityStudent(studentId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysInCourses, degreeType);
            break;
        }
        case SOFTWARE: {
            students[openArrayIndex] = new softwareStudent(studentId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysInCourses, degreeType);
            break;
        }
        case NETWORK: {
            students[openArrayIndex] = new networkStudent(studentId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysInCourses, degreeType);
            break;
        }
        }
        this->lastIndex = openArrayIndex;

    }
```

This is where the exception actually occurs on the (this->students)[i]->print();

```
void roster::printAll()
{
    int currentArrayIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
        if ((this->students)[i] != NULL) {
            (this->students)[i]->print();
        }
        currentArrayIndex++;
    }

}
```

[The can't reads I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzeuo.png)

[Shows correct here though.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHSY4.png)

Per request. Here is student.cpp and secuirityStudent.cpp.

```
student::student()
{
    this->studentId = "";
    this->firstName = "";
    this->lastName = "";
    this->emailAddress = "";
    this->age = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < daysInCoursesArrSize; i++)
        this->daysInCourses[i] = 0;
}

student::student(string studentId, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourses[])
{
    this->studentId = studentId;
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->lastName = lastName;
    this->emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this->age = age;

    for (int i = 0; i < daysInCoursesArrSize; i++) 
        this->daysInCourses[i] = daysInCourses[i];
}

void student::SetStudentId(string studentId) { this->studentId = studentId; }
string student::GetStudentId() { return studentId; }

void student::SetFirstName(string firstName) { this->firstName = firstName; }
string student::GetFirstName() { return firstName; }

void student::SetLastName(string lastName) { this->lastName = lastName; }
string student::GetLastName() { return lastName; }

void student::SetEmailAddress(string emailAddress) { this->emailAddress = emailAddress; }
string student::GetEmailAddress() { return emailAddress; }

void student::SetAge(int age) { this->age = age; }
int student::GetAge() { return age; }

void student::SetDaysInCourses(int daysInCourses[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < daysInCoursesArrSize; i++)
        this->daysInCourses[i] = daysInCourses[i]; 
}
int * student::GetDaysInCourses() { return daysInCourses; }

void student::print() {
    cout << left << setw(10) << studentId;
    cout << left << setw(20) << firstName;
    cout << left << setw(20) << lastName;
    cout << left << setw(30) << emailAddress;
    cout << left << setw(10) << age;
    cout << left << setw(10) << daysInCourses[0];
    cout << left << setw(10) << daysInCourses[1];
    cout << left << setw(10) << daysInCourses[2];
}

student::~student()
{
}


securityStudent::securityStudent() :student()
{
    degreeType = SECURITY;
}

securityStudent::securityStudent(string studentId, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourses[], Degree degreeType)
    : student(studentId, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, age, daysInCourses)
{
    degreeType = SECURITY;
}

Degree securityStudent::GetDegreeType() { return SECURITY; }

void securityStudent::print() {
    this->student::print();
    cout << degreeTypeStrings[degreeType] << "\n";
}

securityStudent::~securityStudent()
{
    student::~student();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the student class and the securityStudent class please?

Comment: Why ‘new student*[capacity]’? And not ‘new student[capacity]’? Is this intended?

Comment: Inside the add function, check that the openArrayIndex is lower than this->capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitely initializing all the pointers to null in the constructor using a for loop.

Comment: Why not just give an {} initializer in the allocation expression? Same result, more elegant and probably more efficient

Comment: What? And even upvoted? Wow. The solution to the problem is: Do not use raw pointers or new or such things. Do not use. Never. In the roster constructor you are allocating student pointer, pointing to a random position in memory. And then using that all over the place. This is a big bug. Refactor your code and eliminate all pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately the instructions require me to use pointers. I agree and I would normally use vectors but that is not allowed.